# How to make sap lumira desktop NOT import big data

Tags: mysql, hadoop, bigdata, sap-lumira

all,

I am using SAP Lumira desktop 1.29 and handle big database. My data is in Mysql and has 8 billion docs in one table.

When I use Lumira to connect to MySql, then It will connect to MySQL, run the query e.g 'select a, b from table1' and import the datasets from MySql. But, here my table is 8 billion docs and it will cost very long-time (several hours) running to import the datasets.

How could I run direct query ( or establish live connection) to MySql database WITHOUT importing the datasets to Lumira?

From SAP lumira, it could also handle big data from Hadoop etc. I have not used hadoop yet, but if every time lumira needs to import whole datasets instead of establishing live connection, how could it handle very big data sets? such as Data in TB scales

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I know, SAP Lumira doesn't support Live connection to any 3rd party datasource except SAP HANA database or SAP BW system.
Please, refer this blog: https://blogs.sap.com/2017/06/10/sap-hana-live-analysis-with-lumira-2.0-an-overview/

Maybe possible solution is to move to SAP Analytics cloud where you can export your MySQL data into cloud HANA.